# Определить максимальную длину подпоследовательности чисел, идущих по возрастанию (не обязательно подряд)

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, комбинаторика

Приветствую. Пытаюсь решить эту учебную задачу довольно продолжительное время, однако так и не придумал подходящего алгоритма.

**Задача.**

Входные данные:

1. Число N (1 <= N <= 10^5) - количество чисел в последовательности;
2. N натуральных чисел Hi (1 <= Hi <= 10^5), записанных через пробел.

Выходные данные:

Длина самой длинной последовательности цифр, идущих по возрастанию, которую можно получить из исходной, убрав из неё некоторые числа, и сохранив порядок оставшихся, и чтобы числа располагались по возрастанию.

**Пример.**

Входные данные:

`10`

`4 3 6 7 9 5 2 8 7 3`

Выходные данные:

`4`

В данном случае есть несколько вариантов:

1. Мы оставляем только числа номер 1, 3, 4, 5 (это числа 4, 6, 7, 9) и убираем все остальные. Длина полученной последовательности 4, 6, 7, 9 - 4.
2. В другом случае мы можем оставить числа номер 2, 3, 4, 8 и убрать все остальные. Тогда длина полученной последовательности 3, 6, 7, 8 тоже 4.

---

Мои варианты решения, которые нуждаются в исправлении:

- Поиск максимального числа в последовательности, затем поиск максимума в части последовательности, которая лежит левее чем первый максимум, и так далее, пока последовательность не закончится. Алгоритм не работает в подобных случаях: `10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, по такому методу длина будет равна 1, хотя на самом деле должна быть 9.
- Решение с использованием деревьев. Приводит к огромному количеству комбинаций для перебора при большой длине последовательности.
- Различные решения перебором. Образуют огромное количество вариантов, которое не поддается перебору.

Буду благодарен за помощь! Не могу придумать сам алгоритм.

Comment: это не так решается. http://e-maxx.ru/algo/longest_increasing_subseq_log где-то на SO вроде бы отвечали даже. И дерево - правильный вариант

Comment: @vp_arth а смысл находить возрастающие цепочки? Таковых может вообще не быть, например: `1 0 2 0 3 0 4`. Здесь нужно убрать нули и тогда получим последовательность `1 2 3 4`. А если возрастающие цепочки искать, то мы найдем `0 2`; `0 3` и `0 4`, что совсем не является правильным.

Comment: Неверно понял задачу, сорян)

Comment: готово!........

Answer (score 2):

**Оптимизированное решение в полной постановке**

*04.02.17*

**Постановка задачи**

Данная задача может быть использована как несложная иллюстрация методов вторичной обработки радиолокационного сигнала, используемых для объединения одиночных целевых отметок в треки (траектории). Успешность подобных методов определяется выбором решающих правил для завязки, сопровождения и сброса треков.

**Решающие правила**

1. *Завязка нового трека*

Каждый новый элемент исходного массива порождает новые треки. При этом один трек появляется "на пустом месте", а остальные возникают как дубликаты треков, продолженных данной отметкой.

2. *Сопровождение трека*

Сопровождение существующего трека заключается в привязке к нему новых точек. Если новая точка имеет большее значение, чем последний элемент трека, её следует дописать в конец трека, а дубликат старого трека использовать для завязки новой траектории (см. п.1).

3. *Сброс трека*

Основанием для сброса трека служит наличие трека такой же длины, имеющего меньший или совпадающий последний элемент. Для реализации этого правила следует предварительно вычислить массив `$last`, в котором хранятся наименьшие последние элементы среди треков одинаковой длины. Когда один из оптимальных треков найден, соответствующее значение массива `$last` декрементируется (это позволяет оставить первый массив среди равноценных и тем самым сэкономить ресурсы).

**О программе**

Программа написана на PHP 7.0 (memory-limit = 512M), этого хватило для решения задачи в исходной постановке.
Решающие правила реализует функция `tracking`. Стандартная функция `array_walk` применена с целью инкапсуляции данных и может быть заменена циклом `foreach`.

Текст программы:

```
$issue = array(4,3,6,7,9,5,2,8,7,3);
print("<b>The longest increasing subsequence</b><br>");

function print_1d($text,$arr){
    print $text;
    foreach($arr as $key=>$item) print "$item ";
}

function print_1dk($text,$arr){
    print $text;
    foreach($arr as $key=>$item) print "$key=>$item&emsp;";
}

function print_longest_track($tracks, $prn=1){
    $track = reset($tracks);
    if($track === false) return;
    $len = count($track);
    if($prn){
        print_1dk("<b><br>maximal track long is:</b> $len<br><b>the first longest track is:</b>&emsp;", $track);
    }else{          
        print("<b><br>maximal track long is:&emsp;</b> $len");
    }
}

function print_track($issue, $key, $track){
    print_1dk("<br><b>track#$key:&emsp;</b> ",$track);
}

function tracking($issue, $prn = 1){
    $len = count($issue);
    $arr = array_count_values($issue);
    $digs = count($arr);
    print"<br><b>tracking:<br>&emsp;</b>length = $len<br>&emsp;digs_all = $digs";
    if($prn>0) print_1d("<br>&emsp;issue:&emsp;",$issue);
    $tracks = [];
    array_walk($issue, function($item, $key) use(&$tracks){
        $old = $tracks;                 // copy of $track
        foreach($old as $k=>$track){
            if($item > end($track)){    
                $tracks[$k][$key] = $item;
                $tracks[] = $track;     // track duplication
            }
        }
        $tracks[] = [$key=>$item];      // new track

        $last = [];                     // array of minimal last tracks' elements
        foreach($tracks as $k=>$track){
            $cnt = count($track);
            if(array_key_exists($cnt, $last)){
                $last[$cnt] = min($last[$cnt], end($track));
            }else{
                $last[$cnt] = end($track);
            }
        }
        $old = $tracks;
        foreach($old as $k=>$track){
            if(end($track) > $last[count($track)]){
                unset($tracks[$k]);
            }elseif(end($track) == $last[count($track)]){
                $last[count($track)]--;
            } 
        }
    });
    return $tracks;
}

$tracks = tracking($issue);
foreach($tracks as $k=>$track) print_track($issue, $k, $track);
print_longest_track($tracks);

$dim = 50;
$dig = 20;
$issue = [];
for($i=0; $i<$dim; $i++) $issue[] = mt_rand(1,$dig);
print "<br><br><b>Model parameters:</b><br>&emsp;dim = $dim<br>&emsp;dig = $dig";
$start_time = microtime(true);
$tracks = tracking($issue);
$time = microtime(true) - $start_time;
foreach($tracks as $k=>$track) print_track($issue, $k, $track);
print_longest_track($tracks);
print"<br>time=$time s";

$dim = 100000;
$dig = 100000;
$issue = [];
for($i=0; $i<$dim; $i++) $issue[] = mt_rand(1,$dig);
print "<br><br><b>Model parameters:</b><br>&emsp;dim = $dim<br>&emsp;dig = $dig";
$start_time = microtime(true);
$tracks = tracking($issue, 0);
$time = microtime(true) - $start_time;
//foreach($tracks as $k=>$track) print_track($issue, $k, $track);
print_longest_track($tracks, 0);
print"<br>time=$time s";
```

Результаты:

```
The longest increasing subsequence

tracking:
 length = 10
 digs_all = 8
 issue: 4 3 6 7 9 5 2 8 7 3 
track#7:  1=>3 2=>6 3=>7 7=>8 
track#14:  1=>3 2=>6 3=>7 
track#19:  6=>2 9=>3 
track#21:  6=>2 
maximal track long is: 4
the first longest track is: 1=>3 2=>6 3=>7 7=>8 

Model parameters:
 dim = 50
 dig = 20
tracking:
 length = 50
 digs_all = 20
 issue: 13 2 4 13 8 2 11 8 1 8 17 14 18 20 11 3 2 6 2 6 5 7 7 5 5 10 20 6 16 5 4 13 10 19 20 6 9 12 6 16 19 13 13 10 4 1 9 9 15 6 
track#159:  8=>1 16=>2 20=>5 27=>6 36=>9 37=>12 41=>13 48=>15 
track#200:  8=>1 16=>2 20=>5 27=>6 36=>9 37=>12 41=>13 
track#201:  8=>1 16=>2 20=>5 27=>6 36=>9 43=>10 
track#202:  8=>1 16=>2 20=>5 27=>6 36=>9 
track#203:  8=>1 16=>2 20=>5 27=>6 
track#208:  8=>1 16=>2 30=>4 
track#209:  8=>1 16=>2 
track#210:  8=>1 
maximal track long is: 8
the first longest track is: 8=>1 16=>2 20=>5 27=>6 36=>9 37=>12 41=>13 48=>15 
time=0.0058760643005371 s

Model parameters:
 dim = 100000
 dig = 100000
tracking:
 length = 100000
 digs_all = 63147
maximal track long is:  614
time=2636.3067319393 s
```

**Вывод**

Задача может быть решена в полной постановке при использовании ресурсов в пределах разумного.

**Упрощённая постановка задачи**

Задачу можно существенно упростить, если искать последовательность из цифр.

Преимущества:

1. Можно использовать строки.
2. Можно организовать цикл не по элементам заданного массива, а по возрастающим последовательностям цифр. При этом нас устраивает первое вхождение требуемой цифры в строку данных.

Программа на PHP:

```
$issue = "4367952873";

function cons($str, $digit=0, $offset=0){
    $result = "";
    for($dig = $digit; $dig <10; $dig++){
        $pos = strpos($str, "$dig", $offset);
        if($pos === false) continue;
        $res = "$dig";
        if(($dig < 9) && ($pos < strlen($str)-1)) $res .= cons($str, $dig+1, $pos+1);
        if(strlen($res) > strlen($result)) $result = $res;
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = cons($issue);
print"issue = $issue&emsp;result = $result";

$issue = "";
for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) $issue .= mt_rand(0,9);
$start_time = microtime(true);
$result = cons($issue);
$time = microtime(true) - $start_time;
print"<br>issue = $issue<br>result = $result&emsp;time=$time s";
```

Результаты:

```
issue = 4367952873 result = 3678
issue = 0555182354809948559984865256825668339416234177738050840225905938638474082013704698992310963416683523337076428903113954261933117989413947690236537966981867130869721226510786916230432006499096065407440756520672084509183488550841598558070812568806165018856214244313271487078313976978568733699287700713476286429602443365477188828625683823652171527665687388325708379548154935321159931437537244361520464660647680127482080204523608100340308980109052034240586157267006762314047561142586853665634605215172451633122515552680467905977512420293169601052649628956069621390832170115155183824803444880613535988857849935014199438917980728593195557761956527921520089879562350088617351008154988221045328229652133611638068827671787578270469330812966523783100707761834259930489437254555730657045349810708432416320686348982548639163146722992601916290702048525148338954351265627397574638411206247006360514149185319209362754711730344243382530888294448483361816753388018414535703917647793109280435077331762139808794867438882960145961930272737808241840861139483868115196158156667264572632081637516761538972632699016092994493172374833109850886676430166241660520953184412592865807495395598364456282200865134303972370276554224150126465589319763904742340604311633976578466273584170487878796611525127403805634512549101667531464532054444074024913339741576837669546255820776408358284642040328369515960113297421121599481278733389551084442605094302942006721348035673557316033055637080241854068108835788825373269973367084388425716050978015962828370685927029847162003686398719546419557356757937498575390687641540955674404756517371802486726767494548182330468183603572978367869847905949605947045694151157492032546914363120838128895174210427439161217832780240242895305505730448190503377086985600994759147971919998540308329686586656612429507878170535378750758674192686947696405387382440802664369714651483685833091325469964419396571268588148182317932588972040252938901720152110731696673295992772709133639329412337216007591294201083155365757769369535022161260047129816822378399711425014676620153465007176031931984108123804115843759490481940881561048236549416522871063693600619820086253988265075512663339318639700974412600670529237938592077975128331920084513113615338056196148154652098751974989869957578696629223654797425062139400338695489771829540036547255783950335645201595865957700009417227129507224505398743613690105625721620908887856202013047082109326781484948517132688709021671053960478296918169774487389934532023193575214016977606218920409486449533921022721968125216759431750383318278527540748233153616859918902726803223831383870899672659920504876634607260930644135386779077598398266703596361803518844705634656938411490708182970258521833676427474239351195373593006153409634837090559124176425655465754009651727184693156905948893786765638084584747706478156819503377658046157848385339026663755238965209078878312720930529245022702088865301427668110449982804474224978950141993203077065133893816413374976586695782902618570391729507716071488795799040920130041592225172560600635242143801920089945700891933687920958202034032022621709921065833518081277609639833061097854824135718591351600042830497192487095293819500904201105798082323955030034960257187127176842690344808537849356489267486991110173189870573123775866898680002948694469812349225176713988553596293348468860515396558243932442008438526392962313523836167341632491403458566579458480234975106126384181435145696621682285737458855559736545091687257128370065166943077102051166278189883055587798023023101178485611372678400719359288487317102189185167452963033639037348686272574765692466732393019980833030339636715626440489775843785147485195972182747425498713508171771756577644777479117430102842817555272672299197404234515249494550207658439779174100015895365393363502794964809184596646777588312699528871497832871334059980971587274881315014721196214081957206459546585995018841685089411097649570139216840479691269494567498634620304013988609321473798372227643766061213435278142861083298135581283387529066719451453976758403674866312945170907278109404481898410278077021644835422289380626603807592848314331424562617013349630712915720565552010027301210620419145346325067191883223653263260740444180530068290720937108178383917662470005407917786788717592543846526781168124080167669188994870366889074927684177619641020850649038020278807165158020077858736861172632827999492938069141442559928272946278894018909472935383592433522990267349173965586315875684611222462661975320802051839611063497662885585498011655446046412771160602095503573675178843836487235509158682325353099031927540769857969334768021987454272741704739140017721691539220110442611823640027113424675260854355533202507209710036939853925309060277410163355378799976419909336107028732415370348775818799889861827622017254494596017631263572812617117805095514437238458851865744188759564336602328628205464228336292032328175163507743717581589824078355564774736251726496469065706577430513440958406292353108550859661749531985363738520704821757686796234124792467390566606272338581595107236988378794928610906673396101123753556709348642613526694441584200720258081148585202794556386396921599323271544136552015909743405496948825525513605605441793884679266376729158307345042747675250628168271575923691134957801288257773256496163636541257403207170682735703550680289978719973666675443942544951167169163003110073770253759379889316486209140329934931529452493759442905650868534304060693627032059353606199105640797449483182563793481608708200911927404379546787872019802396934012127999128074715616630874454450853116086075836106155805908649929217985849758163845622334359943178980432846785710744108233472259465096614699998294683677283112234965537640669986009844671361700885105107134765297926898570723046689932743794121481004246185962429350865273808175407757959023223480612737367480515836091472679447110199843990756748978838717888963562713664493685977531143249542545003234566633131618880030754268242890987326325296317398528468806215452820427397680374737442988830176370005595475586372512854262911226857990572425266097566899161452069746506391167366309802141703793090382108911762553829366115077913127006920133391671280653849025723240057415756375696863819099404423446910270206541744332287947011180069861585902774905813377174840760735919440276648914870783334022928998438812835079973230878734430368812386602967550362022785349654658930260315542776818005209930085214235823908430662308561278373595772348244183951042150740417580003222158933749461124966624015705692784479592979910576163348141922408669626418996789756992364116503764699957989154897965791307358479650306022091305397543486067857012580332281519913463887228208100757921336425720627694755580642750552357798801441562834013280144424029070711021449087208807848457192545935716002441912780113219759303366840775676309755151109156116312606439423957027065675025430779831561618735371780041547197658089064402626600766795507636413264081716954258195913641536621623941619830205284688625724618988143908354619100591236690931865931331094103229404184064003053079492157549364927385691137865179083972455402805887448164708490698037421844537715262715536540273784739628152855162655998137962345883301005133537569428671182538266545149713149183038635510075892487124051328699892943331276311813590555401105333716299368918403529237737890216088454789837596365324941559850898886313053966275669109462475577206429019467215208799434745485837858864838959908185955860288893411229222252577212600174052393200175256693351853950009369281902217214857606435692532025615980454806777674518608767396186127536386260084451430749115198610039081596822264116690155096375953622240040349430019445279216894526436978429574566752420959870686278225098541835440640917588896397103841051961757038564029180436889646110597023912145998312659196832738656080044108457464064653718112409049514416642738396683223589186716462520931271445368008369159511535359220468748432640450089804088880569121016922425479772302241463599312360342349039930128639070443742920035688645657377041563726521102753399373347099780097274120192832385753450864906592675239067049436408814745555502551271827786355963793562859584657451188468393753313609036592187713365043072006364331437818786251447375839642559567799645438243265892098812152952526904676980120222418149174991138796020588033848612569839697867605195720919618518825499875790811739811707873622868257808089887675829699151091495893262496820827600894558537520061653433733944242654317330679593335437778193938421611616529000470477018001456213231594532832175369544263195043595078081980690138634617865586258991439505234778621112230925559778181092771986694323877554807732731860950479180010059223608868812955865509858982580989574372770412902670921103848028418901934345974037711582163928058352926243805385289337936377993139266269688262067398784674437132548216963173642553632783920174708372908016741039591998611826024263377680166809204911887401898030104846816341015794374010951793037605427009431167142288343703677960376590797844066203090842008628532582748481505936762004325830952954465748865709856099750262146657108859802621364490981968348938055648264207491485255959101949222695141791647582563852281561181732598560647640008810928261017115146355976477810121136518630008050375592617998152786041695919258287754730594933565184364042084760676002052131829945603939247393362528134237412436000339467799178816500006311781094967420689706908031122500599060427207494232907054783152344483371065533696352087036928566071432351905601735525448930650891865219882555941617774619113543345281967709027083004677041916635267950711816426582143672559554129490292214738184525660495545680172931177752765608672553221414584559861881887407278611829577218277343653617750189387841610530278886679415465004494182280986707969939165191696226515495859480586070908182179546590388879574637220627257371479026719658997423938834593400718851705002491858269580059389411251559592704122821193152218210167608082696253380925226567925081483035729331765049937901251846572614219290105471849346580410558426034831428533884921
result = 0123456789 time=0.0039651393890381 s
```

Для N=100 000 время счёта такое же. Вычисление длины последовательности трудностей не представляет.

**UPD**

С учётом уточнения понятия цифры, предел возможностей такого подхода демонстрирует следующая программа на PHP:

```
$issue = array(4,3,6,7,9,5,2,8,7,3);
$dig_min = 1;
$dig_max = 99;

function cons($arr, $digit, $offset=0){
    global $dig_max, $level;
    $level++;
    $ar = array_slice($arr, $offset);
    $result = "";
    for($dig = $digit; $dig < $dig_max; $dig++){
        $pos = array_search($dig, $ar);
        if($pos === false) continue;
        $res = "$dig ";
        if(($dig <= $dig_max) && ($pos < count($ar)-1)) 
            $res .= cons($ar, $dig+1, $pos+1);
        if(substr_count($res, " ") > substr_count($result, " ")) $result = $res;
    }
    if($level < 3) print"<br>".str_repeat("&emsp;", $level)."level = $level&emsp;digit = $digit&emsp;result = $result";

    $level--;
    return $result;
}

function print_1d($text,$arr){
    print $text;
    foreach($arr as $item) print $item;
}

$level = 0;
print_1d("<br>issue:",$issue);
$result = cons($issue,$dig_min);
print"&emsp;result = $result";

$level = 0;
$issue = [];
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++) $issue[] = mt_rand(0,99);
print_1d("<br>issue:",$issue);
$start_time = microtime(true);
$result = cons($issue, $dig_min);
$time = microtime(true) - $start_time;
print"&emsp;result = $result";
print"<br>result = $result&emsp;time=$time s";
```

Результаты скромны:

```
issue:4367952873
  level = 2 digit = 3 result = 3 
  level = 2 digit = 4 result = 6 7 8 
  level = 2 digit = 5 result = 6 7 8 
  level = 2 digit = 6 result = 7 
  level = 2 digit = 7 result = 7 8 
  level = 2 digit = 8 result = 8 
  level = 2 digit = 9 result = 
  level = 2 digit = 10 result = 
 level = 1 digit = 1 result = 3 6 7 8  result = 3 6 7 8 
issue:403997771521881192526498019529069301665217591939759236017141530407174576376572273129222349960150686099207812359082797325517335762187579561760751576076421147883578101270874160812892156173
  level = 2 digit = 2 result = 9 14 15 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 3 result = 7 17 21 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 4 result = 7 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 8 result = 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 10 result = 11 14 15 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 11 result = 12 41 60 61 73 
  level = 2 digit = 12 result = 14 15 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 13 result = 17 21 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 15 result = 15 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 16 result = 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 17 result = 21 23 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 18 result = 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 20 result = 21 23 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 21 result = 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 22 result = 23 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 23 result = 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 24 result = 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 28 result = 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 29 result = 61 73 
  level = 2 digit = 31 result = 39 40 45 50 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 32 result = 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 33 result = 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 35 result = 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 36 result = 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 38 result = 50 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 40 result = 40 45 50 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 41 result = 52 64 65 75 76 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 42 result = 60 61 73 
  level = 2 digit = 43 result = 47 60 61 73 
  level = 2 digit = 46 result = 50 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 48 result = 60 61 73 
  level = 2 digit = 51 result = 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 52 result = 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 53 result = 64 65 75 76 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 56 result = 57 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 58 result = 60 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 61 result = 65 68 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 62 result = 76 78 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 65 result = 65 75 76 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 66 result = 75 76 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 69 result = 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 70 result = 75 76 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 71 result = 81 92 
  level = 2 digit = 72 result = 75 76 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 73 result = 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 76 result = 76 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 77 result = 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 78 result = 78 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 79 result = 82 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 82 result = 92 
  level = 2 digit = 83 result = 87 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 88 result = 88 92 
  level = 2 digit = 89 result = 90 91 92 95 
  level = 2 digit = 91 result = 91 92 95 
  level = 2 digit = 92 result = 92 95 
  level = 2 digit = 93 result = 95 
  level = 2 digit = 96 result = 
  level = 2 digit = 98 result = 
  level = 2 digit = 99 result = 
 level = 1 digit = 1 result = 1 9 14 15 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92  result = 1 9 14 15 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92 
result = 1 9 14 15 17 27 31 32 35 51 57 60 76 78 81 92  time=229.34637498856 s
```

Таким образом, решение задачи в полной постановке требует оптимизированных подходов.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы считаете, что каждое число занимает один символ, т. е. лежит в интервале [0;9], но в действительности каждое число лежит в интервале [0;10^5]...

Comment: В заголовке сказано про последовательность цифр

Comment: совершенно верно. Разве 99999 - не цифра? В разделе **входные данные** я описал, какие подаются числа на вход. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не цифра. Но посмотрю)

Comment: да, извините, я имел ввиду не цифры, а числа. Но в условии я описал все корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот трансляция в Питон, псевдо-кода из [Задача поиска наибольшей увеличивающейся подпоследовательности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def max_increasing_subseq_length(numbers):
    # pile is always increasing
    pile = []
    for i, x in enumerate(numbers):
        # Binary search for the largest positive j <= len(pile)
        # such that pile[j] < X[i]
        lo, hi = 0, len(pile)
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo + hi) // 2
            if pile[mid] < x:
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid

        # After searching, lo is 1 greater than the length of the longest
        # prefix of X[i]
        pile[lo:lo+1] = [x]
    return len(pile)

N, numbers = int(input()), list(map(int, input().split()))
assert len(numbers) == N
print(max_increasing_subseq_length(numbers))
```

Это [`O(n log n)`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5) по времени и `O(n)` в памяти алгоритм. [Пример](http://ideone.com/suaZ8y).

Вот [подробное объяснение](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/Longest.pdf) почему жадный алгоритм для [patience sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patience_sorting) (разновидность солитера) находит длину наибольшей увеличивающейся последовательности (равна числу куч карт в конце).