# Найти подмножество последовательных чисел, составленное из K

Tags: c, алгоритм

Помогите с решением задачи.

В массиве найдите подмножество последовательных чисел (элементы нельзя переставлять), составленное из K не обязательно соседних элементов массива (таких подмножеств может быть несколько). Напечатайте элементы массива.

**Нужно модифицировать данный код**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "testing.h"

int main()
{
    int length_subset = 0; //длина искомого подмножества
    int max_length_subset = 0; //длина максимального подмножества

    int start_subset = 0; //начало искомого множества в исходном массиве(переменная содержит адрес элемента массива,с которого начинается искомое множество)

    int original_subset[20]; //исходный массив чисел

    int result_subset[20]; //массив, в котором будут хранится значения искомой последовательности

    int k = 0, j = 0, count_subset = 0; //счетчики

    int end_subset; //конец искомого подмножества в исходном массиве(переменная содержит адрес элемента массива,на котором заканчивается искомое множество)

    int quantity_elements; // количество элементов подмножества

    int m = 0; //длина массива

               //Ввести длину массива

               //Вывести на экран сообщение "Enter lenght of array: "
    input_printf("Enter lenght of array: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);

    //Проверить ее корректность
    if (m < 2 || m > 20)
    {
        //Вывести на экран сообщение "No solution"
        printf("Invalid input data");
        WAIT_ANY_KEY
        return 0;
    }

    //Ввести элементы массива
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        //Вывести на экран сообщение "Enter element of array: "
        input_printf("Enter element of array: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &original_subset[i]);

        //Проверить их корректность
        if (original_subset[i] > 1000 || original_subset[i] < -1000)
        {
            //Вывести на экран сообщение "No solution"
            error_printf("Invalid input data");
            WAIT_ANY_KEY
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //Найти максимальные подмножества последовательных чисел в данном массиве
    //Для всех элементов массива
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        length_subset = 0;
        start_subset = 0;

        //Пока текущий элемент массива + 1 = следующему элементу массива
        while ((original_subset[j] + 1) == (original_subset[j + 1]))
        {
            ++length_subset; //увеличить длину искомого подмножества на единицу
            j++;

            if (start_subset == 0) //условие для того,чтобы переменная инициализировалась только один раз
            {
                start_subset = i;
            }
        }

        ++length_subset; //увеличить длину, т.к. для последнего члена условие while не выполняется

                         //Определить конец удаляемой последовательности
        end_subset = start_subset + length_subset; //конец удаляемой последовательности

     //Если текущее количество = максимальному количеству 
        if (max_length_subset == length_subset && max_length_subset > 1) //искомые множества равны, записать и оставить предыдущее
        {
            //Записать значения элементов в результирующий массив
            for (start_subset; start_subset < end_subset; start_subset++)
            {
                result_subset[k] = original_subset[start_subset];
                k++; //k здесь не меняется изначально, записывать начнет с того места, где было записано последнее
            }
            quantity_elements += length_subset; //увеличить количество элементов, т.к. добавлено множество
        }

        //Если текущее количество > максимального количества
        else if (max_length_subset < length_subset && length_subset > 1)
        {
            max_length_subset = length_subset; //присвоить текущее значение максимальному
            k = 0; //k здесь обнуляется, т.к. найдено большее множество и нужно записать только его и сначала

                   //Записать значения элементов в результирующий массив
            for (start_subset; start_subset < end_subset; start_subset++)
            {
                result_subset[k] = original_subset[start_subset];
                k++;
            }
            quantity_elements = length_subset; //обновить количество элементов
        }
    }

    //Если в массиве нет подмножеств
    //Если число последовательных элементов в подмножестве равно 0  
    if (max_length_subset == 0)
    {
        //Вывести на экран сообщение "No solution"
        printf("no solution");
        WAIT_ANY_KEY
        return 0;
    }

    //Вывести результирующие подмножества
    else
    {
        printf("\n\n\n"); //переход на 3 строки вниз

                          //Вывести все элементы подмножеств
        for (k = 0; k < quantity_elements; k++)
        {
            //Вывести на экран текущий элемент массива
            printf("%d ", result_subset[k]);


            count_subset++;

            //Выполнить перенос строки через максимальное количество элементов в подмножестве
            if (count_subset == max_length_subset)
            {
                printf("\n");
                count_subset = 0;
            }
        }

        WAIT_ANY_KEY
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Например, тест: -7;1;3;4;-2;2;5;6. Результат: 1,2, 3,4, 4,5, 5,6

Comment: В чём вы видите проблему с кодом? Что вы ожидали получить? Что вместо этого происходит? Не помещайте необходимую для ответа информацию в комментарии, отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите кнопку [edit].

Comment: @ourcode последовательность должна быть возрастающей? нигде не сказано, но судя по комменту это так

Comment: @Schullz Да, возрастающей.

Comment: @jfs я вижу проблему, что не пойму как это реализовать, ибо в моем коде подмножества находятся последовательно за собой, а здесь они могут находится не по соседству.

Comment: В вашем вопросе отсутствует вопрос. «Исправьте вот эту простыню кода» — не вопрос.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Определить максимальную длину подпоследовательности чисел, идущих по возрастанию (не обязательно подряд)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621020/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Два алгоритма: один прямолинейный квадратичный `O(n**2)`, другой оптимальный однопроходной `O(n)`.

## O(n**2) по времени, O(k) в памяти алгоритм

Алгоритм: для каждого элемента в массиве `X`, строим подпоследовательности, начинающиеся с этого элемента и
состоящие из последовательных чисел (но индексы могут быть не подряд), до тех пор пока длина подпоследовательности не равна искомой (не нашли решение).

Текущая подпоследовательность представлена массивом индексов `M`, таких что

```
X[M[i]] + 1 == X[M[i+1]]
```

для всех возможных `i` (выражает условие последовательности чисел):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** Fill *M* such that: all(X[M[i]] == X[M[i+1]] - 1 for i in range(k-1)).
 *
 * Return whether found the natural subsequence (managed to fill *M*).
 */
bool find_natural_subsequence(int *X, size_t n, int* M, size_t k)
{
  if (k == 0)
    return true; /* empty result (M), do nothing */
  else if (k == 1) {
    if (n > 0) {
      M[0] = 0; /* [X[0]]: any subsequence with one item will do */
      return true;
    }
  } else { /* k > 1 */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      size_t last = 0;  /* index of the last filled M value */
      M[last] = i;  /* check the subsequence starting here */
      for (size_t j = i + 1;  j < n; ++j) {
        if (X[M[last]] == X[j] - 1)  { /* found the next item */
          M[++last] = j;
          if (last == k-1)
            return true; /* found the subsequence */
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false; /* not found */
}
```

Это квадратичный алгоритм (`O(n**2)` время, `O(k)` памяти под результат). Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int k = 4;
  int X[] = {-7, 1, 3, 4, -2, 2, 5, 6};
  int M[k];
  if(find_natural_subsequence(X, sizeof(X)/sizeof(*X), M, k)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
      printf("%d ", X[M[i]]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
  }
  fputs("not found\n", stderr);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
}
```

Результат:

```
$ cc *.c && ./a.out
3 4 5 6
```

## O(n) по времени и памяти алгоритм

Можно улучшить алгоритм и сделать его `O(n)` (линейным однопроходным), используя `O(n)` памяти (*стек* здесь как стопка карт, в которой мы видим значение только самой последней (верхней) карты):

1. Если входной размер нулевой, то возвращаем пустой список
2. Для каждого элемента в коллекции вынимаем стек где элемент на единицу больше вершины стека, чтобы последовательные числа получить в каждом стеке. Если не нашли подходящий стек, то создаём новый пустой стек.
3. Добавляем элемент в стек (наверх, последним)
4. Если размер стека равен искомому, то возвращаем его
5. Добавляем стек назад, индексируя по новому последнему элементу. Если место уже занято, то оставляем более высокий (длинный) стек.

На Питоне это можно выразить как:

```py
def find_natural_subsequence(iterable, size):
    if size == 0:
        return []  # 1. empty pile

    piles = {} # mapping: <top of the pile> -> pile
    for x in iterable:
        # 2. extract the pile where we can put `x`: <top of the pile> + 1 == x
        pile = piles.pop(x-1, []) # O(1)

        # 3. add x to the pile (push on top)
        pile.append(x) # O(1)

        # 4. found the subsequence
        if len(pile) == size: 
            return pile

        # 5. put it back
        piles[x] = max(pile, piles.pop(x, ()), key=len) # O(1)

    raise ValueError((iterable, size))
```

Пример:

```
>>> find_natural_subsequence([-7, 1, 3, 4, -2, 2, 5, 6], 4)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Вот [визуализация, которая показывает как стопки (стеки), представленные `piles` в коде, растут](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20find_natural_subsequence%28iterable,%20size%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20size%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%20%20%23%201.%20empty%20pile%0A%0A%20%20%20%20piles%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20%23%20mapping%3A%20%3Clast%20in%20pile%3E%20-%3E%20pile%0A%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20iterable%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%202.%20extract%20the%20pile%20where%20to%20put%20x%3A%20%3Clast%20in%20the%20pile%3E%20%2B%201%20%3D%3D%20x%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pile%20%3D%20piles.pop%28x-1,%20%5B%5D%29%20%23%20O%281%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%203.%20add%20x%20to%20the%20pile%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pile.append%28x%29%20%23%20O%281%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%204.%20found%20the%20subsequence%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20len%28pile%29%20%3D%3D%20size%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20pile%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%205.%20put%20it%20back%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20piles%5Bx%5D%20%3D%20max%28pile,%20piles.pop%28x,%20%28%29%29,%20key%3Dlen%29%20%23%20O%281%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20raise%20ValueError%28%28iterable,%20size%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28find_natural_subsequence%28%5B-7,%201,%203,%204,%20-2,%202,%205,%206%5D,%204%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=37&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Для реализации на С++, можно использовать `std::unordered_map`, чтобы представить `piles` и `std::vector` для каждого стека.