# Последовательность символов в алфавитном порядке без циклов, условных операторов,

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Задание: выделить из строки самую длинную последовательность символов, которые расположены в алфавитном порядке.
Условия выполнения: использовать только парадигму функционального программирования(вызовы функций, определение анонимных функций на основе вызовов других функций, рекурсия, специальные функции, которые реализуют возможности функционального программирования;
Запрещено использовать циклы, условные операторы, операторы присвоения, операторы контроля кроме return).

Comment: И где же ваши попытки?

Comment: Впервые столкнулся с функциональной парадигмой, даже не знаю с какой стороны подступиться. Не пойму как при таких условиях в лямбда-функциях задать сравнение текущего элемента списка с предыдущим.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Найти подмножество последовательных чисел, составленное из K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654656/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Если подряд элементы должны идти, чтобы найти самую длинную подстроку с символами в алфавитном порядке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from itertools import groupby

print(max((''.join([c for _, c in g])
           for _, g in groupby(enumerate(s), key=lambda (i, c): i-ord(c))),
          key=len))
```

К примеру, для `s = '12a3bc4def5gh'`, результат: `def`.

Решение основано на [примере из itertools документации о поиске подряд идущих последовательных чисел](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples). Суть решения в вычислении разницы с подряд идущими индексами, которые `enumerate()` генерирует.

Этот код использует циклы, которые можно заменить на рекурсивные вызовы. К примеру, вот рекурсивная реализация `max()` без явных циклов [Найти максимум одномерного массива c помощью рекурсии C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519102/23044)

Явные циклы можно заменить на неявные с помощью "функциональной" функции `map()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

print(max(map(lambda (_, g): ''.join(map(itemgetter(1), g)), 
              groupby(enumerate(s), key=lambda (i, c): i-ord(c))),
          key=len))
```

Выглядит устрашающе, но нет ни одного цикла.