# Найти непрерывные последовательности чисел в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, коллекции

Как преобразовать список чисел `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,25,26,27]` в строку вида `"1...9, 11, 25...27"`?

Принцип преобразования:
дан конкретный список, в котором нужно найти последовательность из чисел и между минимальным и максимальным числом в этой последовательности поставить `"..."`, если последовательность прерывается поставить `","`

Comment: Добавьте свои попытки (свой код).

Comment: Мб если бы вы попытались сами, или предложили свои догадки. Объяснили чётко принцип по которому они разбиваются. То вам можно было бы помочь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list

Comment: Принцип простой - дан конкретный список, в котором нужно найти последовательность из чисел и между минимальным и максимальным числом в этой последовательности поставить "...", если последовательность прерывается поставить ",".

Comment: связанный вопрос [Последовательность символов в алфавитном порядке без циклов, условных операторов,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796329/23044)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Немного доработал [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2361991/5909792):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter, sub

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 25, 26, 27]

result = []

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda x: sub(*x)):
    items = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))
    if len(items) > 1:
        result.append('{}...{}'.format(items[0], items[-1]))
    else:
        result.append(str(items[0]))

print(', '.join(result))  # 1...9, 11, 25...27
```

---

Вариант выше имел много функциональных элементов, которые тут заменил:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 25, 26, 27]

result = []

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda x: x[0]-x[1]):
    items = [i[1] for i in g]
    if len(items) > 1:
        result.append('{}...{}'.format(items[0], items[-1]))
    else:
        result.append(str(items[0]))

print(', '.join(result))  # 1...9, 11, 25...27
```

Comment: Спасибо, так намного понятней!

Answer (score 5):

Как я понял вам нужно разделить один список на список где каждое следующие число равно предыдущему + 1 
Можно примерно так, версия на англоязычном ресурсе

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
ranges = sum((list(t) for t in zip(arr, arr[1:]) if t[0] + 1 != t[1]), [])
iranges = iter(arr[0:1] + ranges + arr[-1:])
print(', '.join([str(n) + '...' + str(next(iranges)) for n in iranges]))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361945/detecting-consecutive-integers-in-a-list

Comment: для ввода в вопросе это печатает: `1...9, 11...11, 25...27`, а должно быть: `1...9, 11, 25...27`.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант, основанный на [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import count, groupby
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,25,26,27]
>>> consecutive = lambda n, it=count(): next(it) - n
>>> ', '.join([f'{first}...{rest[-1]}' if rest else str(first)
...            for _, (first, *rest) in groupby(L, key=consecutive)])
'1...9, 11, 25...27'
```

Как `groupby()` генерирует прогоны последовательных номеров здесь:

- [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) группирует идущие подряд элементы в списке `L`, для которых `key` функция (`consecutive()`), возвращает одинаковые значения
- [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) это итератор, представляющий натуральные числа, поэтому `next(it)` возвращает следующее натуральное число на каждом вызове
- `next(it) - n` разница одинаковая для непрерывной подпоследовательности целых чисел, к примеру, `4, 5, 6`. Левые и правые части в разнице увеличиваются ровно на единицу

`(first, *rest)` разбивает прогон последовательных чисел на первое и все последующие. См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

`if rest` проверяет, есть ли ещё числа или только первое (как в случае с `11` в этом примере). Если ещё числа есть, то создаётся диапазон `a...b`, используя [`f''`-строку из Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

`','.join()` объединяет список строк в одну строку через запятую.